# Make Row vertically horizontally

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I have a `Row` of `CircularProfileAvatar` and I want to make them horizontally scrollable, but I can't figure out how with `ListView`.
Here is my code:

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
   children: <Widget>[
     CircularProfileAvatar(
       ...
     ),
     CircularProfileAvatar(
       ...
     ),
     CircularProfileAvatar(
       ...
     ),
     CircularProfileAvatar(
       ...
     ),
   ]
),
```

I want to make everything in that `Row` horizontally Scrollable. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: vertically scrollable ? or horizontally scrollable @Mo711

Comment: @T.TSage sorry meant horizontally

Comment: You can use a `ListView` widget to achieve that @Mo711

Comment: @T.TSage yes I know, but I couldn't figure out in what way

Comment: Since the `ListView` takes a children widget, You can replace the `Row` with a ListView @Mo711. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
Container(
      // give a custom height
      height: 400,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView(
        // set the scroll direction to horizontal
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProfileAvatar(
            ...
            ),
            CircularProfileAvatar(
            ...
            ),
            CircularProfileAvatar(
            ...
            ),
            CircularProfileAvatar(
            ...
            ),
          ]
      ),
    );
```

To add spaces in between your `CircleProfileAvatar`, you can use a `SizedBox` widget and give it a `width` property.

Like:

```
SizedBox(
  // set your desired width here
  width: 50,
   );
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a gap between these CircularProfileAvatars?